# C Programming Basics

Tags: c

Why does the code given below Prints b on the Screen?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float a = 5.6;
    if(a == 5.6)
    {
        printf("a");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("b");    
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not compare with floating numbers in this way.

Comment: It is not a good idea to compare floats for exact equality.

Comment: A decimal in C is by default a double and float has lower precision than a double.Here 'a' is float and hence when compared with the same valued double doesn't give what you expect.Infact, when you replace == with > in the program, still b will be printed on screen as double has higher precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As floating point Numbers can't be matched exactly (because between each 2 numbers you choose are infinite other numbers). A machine can't represent them all and is forced to represent them with a moddel of only some floating point numbers it is able to represent.

So in your case, the system is probably not storing `5.6` because that's a number your machine doesn't want to represent. Instead it is storing something which is pretty close to `5.6` into the memory.

So if you do comparing with floating point numbers you never should check for equivalenz. Instead you should use the system C define `FLT_EPSILON` and check for

```
if (((a - 5.6) > -FLT_EPSILON) && ((a - 5.6) < FLT_EPSILON))
{
    ...
}
```

Where `FLT_EPSILON` is the smallest representable float type value.
So if the difference from a to 5.6 is absolute smaller as EPSILON, you can be sure it WAS equal, but the machine has chosen the next number it knows instead of `5.6`.

The same would be DBL_EPSILON for double type.

this types are defined in `float.h`

Comment: I would use `if ( fabs( a - 5.6 ) < E )` instead of the expanded version.

Comment: @concept3d Yeah but if you want high performance, I wouldn't. If performance isn't the critical point fabs() is the better to read way, that I agree with so far.

Comment: I don't agree with the performance point, fabs will actually be reduced to a single instruction on most hardware. And even if it didn't the performance will hardly be any different (both version have two branches).

Comment: @concept3d But the `&&` breaks allready if it is out of EPSILON space in first case. So anyway I will at least save the time of a single function call. And Even a function call takes time for stack pus and poping.

Comment: But as I already said: ofcourse `fabs()` is the prettyer way.

Comment: fabs will actually be reduced to a single instruction on most hardware.

Answer (score 2):

When you want a float value don't forget to add `f`

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float a = 5.6f;
    if(a == 5.6f)
    {
        printf("a");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("b");    
    }
}
```

prints `a` as expected.

The problem was that both `5.6` are defined as `double` literals, and the `a` got converted into a `float` while in the `if` it's still comparing it to a `double` value so you get false.

Actually adding `f` only inside the if would be enough, but better safe then sorry.

Comment: Though this worked by eliminating the cast between float and double, but I don't think absolute equality comparison with non integers are valid.

Answer (score 0):

floating point number in c is double by default. If you want use as float you need to add `f` at end of the number. try below code it gives `a`

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float a = 5.6;
    if(a == 5.6f)
    {
        printf("a");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("b");    
    }
```